# Efficiently creating a column containing a sequence of values concatenated from rows in a different column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to create a new column containing a sequence of values given in a different column, for the rows above and below a given position. Let's work better this with an example.

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- tibble(POS = c("A","C","G","G","C","C","C","A","A","G","T","C","A"),
             GET = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))

# A tibble: 13 x 2
   POS   GET  
   <chr> <lgl>
 1 A     FALSE
 2 C     FALSE
 3 G     FALSE
 4 G     FALSE
 5 C     TRUE 
 6 C     FALSE
 7 C     FALSE
 8 A     FALSE
 9 A     FALSE
10 G     FALSE
11 T     FALSE
12 C     TRUE 
13 A     FALSE
```

Given a row number `i`, and a window size, I'd like to concatenate the values in `POS` to generate a sequence, `SEQ`. For example, if the window extension is 2 (because it extends two rows above and two below), the `SEQ` value for the first observation would be just "ACG", but it would be "ACGGCC" for the third one.

However, I just want to do this for a few observations, the ones with `GET==TRUE`, so ideally an output would look like the following:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  POS   GET   SEQ  
  <chr> <lgl> <chr>
1 C     TRUE  GGCCC
2 C     TRUE  GTCA
```

In any case, a solution with the `SEQ` value for all rows would also be valid, what I am looking for is actually not a solution for the problem itself, but an efficient one (see below).

**How I do it**

This is the code I have work out:

```
window_extension <- 2
size <- window_extension * 2 + 1

for (i in 1:size) {
  if (i <= window_extension) {
     df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(!!paste("SEQ", i, sep="") := dplyr::lag(POS, window_extension + 1 - i))
  } else if (i > window_extension + 1) {
    df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(!!paste("SEQ", i, sep="") := dplyr::lead(POS, window_extension - (size-i)))
  } else {
    df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(!!paste("SEQ", i, sep="") := POS)
  }
}

df %>% tidyr::unite("SEQ", tidyselect::starts_with("S"), sep="", remove = TRUE, na.rm=TRUE) %>% dplyr::filter(GET)
```

The problem with this solution is that it generates an intermediate dataframe (`df` just after the loop) with as many columns as indicated by the `size` variable. So you can imagine that if `size` is big, the burden in memory gets bigger. This is a problem by itself, specially when only a few rows are of actual interest. Too much wasted memory.

Hopefully there will be some dedicated function to achieve this. I expected to work out something with dplyr lag and lead, but no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi elcortegano, that example tibble looks suspiciously like DNA sequence. Perhaps you could provide a little more information about the problem, as your issue may have been previously solved. Perhaps you have a list of genomic positions and you want to extract sequence of varying size around that position?

Comment: This is in fact a DNA sequence. The goal is to retrieve the sequence surrounding some positions of interest. So that if the window extension is 2 bp as above, we would get 5 bp regions, centered at that position of interest.

Comment: How do you determine `GET` is it just a genomic position? Are you using a reference genome? BAM file?

Comment: `GET` here are mutations. I am omitting here fields like the chromosome, genome position or alternate allele, but yes, we do have FASTA reference, BAM and VCF files. I was working with this processed genome we got on a huge TSV file (for running GLM with some parameters), but I'm just wondering if perhaps this task could be better done with something like bedtools?

Comment: In my opinion, the approach listed in the question is suboptimal. `bedtools` or using the `GenomicRanges` package would be much better.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you for the discussion because it really opened my eyes.

Comment: Good luck. You might also consider asking on http://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ if you need more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)


df <- tibble(POS = c("A","C","G","G","C","C","C","A","A","G","T","C","A"),
             GET = c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))


df$SEQ <- slider::slide(df$POS, ~.x, .before = 2, .after = 2) %>% sapply(paste, collapse = "")

df %>%
  filter(GET)
```

Comment: Didn't know about `slider` but really looks awesome, and does the job even in a simpler way, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution can help, you have to set `k`:

```
#Define k
k <- 2
#Create index
index <- which(df$GET==T)
index2 <- 1:length(index)
index3 <- index-k
index4 <- index+k
#Replace
index3 <- ifelse(index3>dim(df)[1],dim(df)[1],index3)
index4 <- ifelse(index4>dim(df)[1],dim(df)[1],index4)
#Assign
df$i <- NA
#Loop
for(i in index2)
{
  df$i[index[i]] <- paste0(df$POS[index3[i]:index4[i]],collapse = '')
}
#Now filter
df2 <- df[!is.na(df$i),]
df2

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  POS   GET   i    
  <chr> <lgl> <chr>
1 C     TRUE  GGCCC
2 C     TRUE  GTCA
```

Comment: Well this certainly looks much more efficient and simple, thank you for posting this!! For this specific problem (with DNA sequences), the program bedtools for genomic will work better, as commented with Ian Campbell above, but hope this can be of utility for other users with a similar problem in different contexts!

Comment: @elcortegano Great! I hope in any way it could help!